# Mandrill: Can you make template_content null?

Tags: json, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm trying to send templated emails through mandrill using the Messages/send-template.json API. This API requires that to inject template_content as "name" and "content" in the JSON you deliver. In my templates, however, I don't need any injected content. Is it possible to pass null values in these fields and still use templates?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing here was just passing empty strings to "name" and "content" like:

```
"template_content": [
{
"name": "",
"content": "",
}
]
```